# How to use OTG Data Cable with a Nexus S to access?

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, samsung-nexus-s, usb-on-the-go

Having an [OTG Data Cable](http://dx.com/p/micro-5pin-to-usb-female-otg-data-cable-black-129671), I connected different thumb drives to my Nexus S – running JB 4.1.2 – but my phone doesn't seem to read them. The thumb drives I tried are:

- a 16GB Kingston G3 Data Traveler USB 2.0
- a 16GB Sandisk Cruzer Fit Mini USB 2.0
- and a 2GB generic drive

What else is needed in order to access that memory?

Is there anything along the lines of the [Nexus Media Importer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.homeysoft.nexususb.importer) but for Nexus S?

Comment: Does anything show up at all in settings->storage? It should show up as USB storage.. Use [ES file explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop).

Comment: No new USB storage showing up.

Comment: Also tried with the [ASTRO File Manager/Browser](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.metago.astro) – still not showing up.

Comment: You might want to check your device's capabilities with e.g. chainfire's [USB Host Diagnostics](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.chainfire.usbhostdiagnostics), or try [Usb Host Controller](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=hu.sztupy.android.usbhostcontroller) which promises to manage devices connected via host mode. Both worth a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also have a Nexus S device (running CyanogenMod 11, Android 4.4.4 KitKat), and it seems Nexus S does not support USB OTG. I tried connecting an external USB keyboard and also a USB mouse, and it did not work. The mouse LED for the optical sensor did not even light up.

So, I believe that either the hardware does not have support for USB OTG, or you might need a custom firmware with a custom kernel to make it work (I believe this is unlikely).